# vb.net loading tab pages on demand

Tags: .net, vb.net, tabs

I have a desktop application in vb.net. The tab control has around 13 tabs. 
All these tabs have windows controls in them and they are populated with data from sql server locally.
The first time the application runs, it takes a lot of time for these tabs to load. Is there a way to make sure only the first tab is loaded and next ones are loaded on click or demand?

Answer (score 0):

You can juste populate data for the first tab in Form_load,and then handel the event `tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged` for populate just the selected tab like :

```
  private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (tabControl1.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                //Populate seconde tab
            }
            else if (tabControl1.SelectedIndex == 2)
            {
                 //Populate the third tab
            }

        }
```

Comment: Looks fine, but don't forget to clear the previous tab if you want to keep it minimal.

Comment: Also he can test if the controls of the activated tab are empty ,if they are already populated he can jump the code how populate data